# Datetime without time !

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm using the following statement to generate random dates:

```
DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 1, GETDATE()) - 1 - FLOOR(RAND(CAST(NEWID() AS binary(4))) * 365.25 * 90), 10)
```

But, I'm getting the following format:

1974-01-28 00:00:00.000

How can I get rid of time part 00:00:00.000 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are on SQL Server 2008 then use the `date` datatype instead of `datetime` otherwise you can't. The `datetime` datatype always has a time component stored with it.

You can remove it for display purposes though by casting to a character datatype and passing a style argument. e.g.

```
select CONVERT(varchar,GETDATE(),105)
```

Returns

```
30-12-2010
```

Quite a comprehensive cheat sheet to these formats [is here](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the DATE data type instead of the DATETIME datatime if you are using SQL Server 2008.

Or, you can use the CONVERT function to convert the date to a string-type (VARCHAR, CHAR, etc.) data type.

For example

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 101)
```

produces this

```
12/29/2010
```

More on [CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) formats

Answer (score 0):

You can't keeping it as `Datetime`, unless you have SQL Server 2008 and use the `Date` datatype